# What can I craft at the new crafting stations in 1.2.3?

Tags: terraria

Amongst the changes listed on the (very long) [1.2.3 changelog](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/terraria-1-2-3.132539/), are these two:

- Added 8 new crafting stations.
- Added Heavy Workbench.

What are these new crafting stations, and what can I make with them? I see that **Copper Plating**, **Stone Slabs**, and **Sandstone Slabs** are craftable from the heavy workbench, but are there other new items I can make?

Comment: The change log lists all items. Have you checked the wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's it for the heavy workbench, the others seem to be for use in crafting the 80-something plus furniture types added, like the living loom to make the living wood furniture set, the honey dispenser to make the honey furniture set, the glass kiln to make the glass furniture set and so on and so forth. If you ask the guide what you can make with torches then most of it comes up (if not all).

Answer (score 1):

The following new crafting stations appear to be available in 1.2.3 (there are actually nine new ones, excluding the heavy work bench, unless I've got one of these wrong):

1. **[Bone Welder](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Bone_Welder)**: Used to make bone furniture
2. **[Flesh Cloning Vaat](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Flesh_Cloning_Vaat)**: Used to make flesh furniture
3. **[Glass Kiln](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Glass_Kiln)**: Used to make glass furniture (also bottles)
4. **[Heavy Work Bench](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Heavy_Work_Bench)**: Used to make stone slab, sandstone slab, and copper plating
5. **[Honey Dispenser](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Honey_Dispenser)**: Used to make honey furniture
6. **[Ice Machine](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ice_Machine)**: Used to make ice furniture
7. **[Lihzahrd Furnace](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lihzahrd_Furnace)**: Used to make Lihzahrd furniture
8. **[Living Loom](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Living_Loom)**: Used to make living wood furniture
9. **[Sky Mill](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Sky_Mill)**: Used to make skyware furniture
10. **[Steampunk Boiler](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Steampunk_Boiler)**: Used to make steampunk furniture